# When running the 'python' command, why would I use the -u flag?

Tags: python, shell

Here's what the manual says but I don't understand:

> Force  stdin,  stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems
> where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
> Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(),  readlines()
> and file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not
> influenced by this option.  To work around this,  you  will  want  to
> use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python opens the `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderror` streams in a buffered mode. Python will read or write in larger chunks, keeping data in memory until a threshold is reached. `-u` disables those buffers.

Details of data buffering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer

Also, Python can interpret newlines on open files and translate them from and to the native platform newlines (text mode). The `-u` option disables this translation, allowing you to process binary data without having to worry about what might happen to `\r\n` combinations. It is the equivalent of using `rb` or `wb` modes when opening files with the `open()` function.